# Nodejs and java socket implementation Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

I am getting following error while running socket implementation with nodejs and java 
        events.js:160
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

```
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

Comment: Is that port already used by another process?

Comment: @VenkatChaitanyaSama If it was, the error message would be different.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect to localhost: 8081. Is any service running on your localhost and on this port? If not, the connection is refused which cause this error. I would suggest checking if there is anything running on localhost:8081 first.

Comment: Thankyou. Another server was running on same port.